# Programming Dart in Sublime Text 3, Changing Path to dart-sdk

Tags: javascript, dart, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I downloaded Sublime Text 3 on my 14.04 Ubuntu machine, installed Package Control, and installed the Dart Plugin. I also have the dart-sdk that I downloaded from dartlang.

I went into the user preferences file in Sublime Text and added

```
"dart_sdk_path": "/home/arnold/Documents/dart/dart-sdk",
```

For good measure, I also tried

```
"dartsdk_path": "/home/arnold/Documents/dart/dart-sdk",
"dart-sdk_path": "/home/arnold/Documents/dart/dart-sdk",
```

When I try to compile to JavaScript using dart2js, with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and selecting Build: Dart: dart2js, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dart2js'
[cmd: ['dart2js', '--minify', '-o/home/arnold/Documents/ECE161/Python/Flask/templates/dart.html.js', '/home/arnold/Documents/ECE161/Python/Flask/templates/dart.html']]
[dir: /home/arnold/Documents/ECE161/Python/Flask]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
[Finished]
```

I've already told Sublime Text where the sdk is, right? So why is it pointing to

```
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

and how can I fix this, if that's the issue.

Comment: You have to make sure that your PATH environment variable includes the path to the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `PATH` environment variable includes the path to the `dart-sdk/bin` directory. This should be enough if you have only one Dart version installed at one time.